# Retrieving multiple min occurrences from a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of custom objects:

```
List<CustomObject> customObjects;
```

from which I would like to extract all the objects that have the have the earliest datetime value set.

So the class would look something like this:

```
class CustomObject {
   LocalDateTime date;

   public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
       return date;
   }
}
```

and I'm able to successfully find the object in the list with the earliest date with a custom comparator function like this:

```
private static LocalDateTime getDate(CustomObject customObject) {
        return customObject.getDateTime();
}

CustomObject customObjectMin = customObjects.stream().
           min(Comparator.comparing(MyUtilClass::getDate));
```

However, it is possible to have multiple custom objects with the same date, but it looks like there is no way to get multiple occurrences in that scenario with the `min`. Is there an easy solution to finding all the objects in the list with the earliest date set ? Something like this:

```
List<CustomObject> customObjectsMin = customObjects.stream().
           minWithAllOccurences(Comparator.comparing(MyUtilClass::getDate));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two selections.

- one to find the min date
- one to find those with that date

e.g.

```
LocalDate min = customObjects.stream()
                             .map(CustomObject::getDateTime)
                             .min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
List<CustomObject> objs = customObjects.stream()
                             .filter(c -> min.equals(c.getDateTime()))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can use Collectors.groupingBy into a TreeMap and take the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Peter Lawrey's excellent answer, I would like to point out that it is possible to do this with a single stream while avoiding the memory costs of collecting every element into a TreeMap. How? One way would be to use `reduce()`, as follows:

```
List<SampleJava> customObjectsMin = customObjects.stream()
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), // identity
        (List<SampleJava> list, SampleJava item) -> { // accumulate
            if(list.isEmpty() ||  getDate(item).compareTo(getDate(list.get(0))) < 0) {
                return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(item));
            } else if(getDate(item).equals(getDate(list.get(0)))) {
                list.add(item);
            }
            return list;
        },
        (list1, list2) -> { // combine
            if(list1.isEmpty()) return list2; 
            if(list2.isEmpty()) return list1; 
            int cmp = getDate(list1.get(0)).compareTo(getDate(list2.get(0)));
            if(cmp < 0) return list1;
            if(cmp > 0) return list2;
            list1.addAll(list2);
            return list1;
        });
```